# I am trying to groupby values in a specific column that holds multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this huge netflix dataset which I am trying to see which actors appeared in the most movies/tv shows specifically in America. First, I created a list of unique actors from the dataset. Then created a nested for loop to loop through each name in list3(containing unique actors which checked each row in df3(filtered dataset with 2000+rows) if the column cast contained the current actors name from list3. I believe using iterrows takes too long

```
myDict1 = {}


for name in list3:
    if name not in myDict1:
        myDict1[name] = 0
    for index, row in df3.iterrows():
        if name in row["cast"]:
            myDict1[name] += 1
            
myDict1
```

| Title | cast |
| --- | --- |
| Movie1 | Robert De Niro, Al Pacino, Tarantino |
| Movie2 | Tom Hanks, Robert De Niro, Tom Cruise |
| Movie3 | Tom Cruise, Zendaya, Seth Rogen |

I want my output to be like this:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Robert De Niro | 2 |
| Tom Cruise | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
out = df['cast'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
out = pd.DataFrame({'Name': out.index, 'Count': out.values})


>>> out
             Name  Count
0      Tom Cruise      2
1  Robert De Niro      2
2         Zendaya      1
3      Seth Rogen      1
4       Tarantino      1
5       Al Pacino      1
6       Tom Hanks      1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this! This was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
l=['Robert De Niro','Tom Cruise']#list

df=df.assign(cast=df['cast'].str.split(',')).apply(pd.Series.explode)#convert cast into list and explode
df[df['cast'].str.contains("|".join(l))].groupby('cast').size().reset_index().rename(columns={'cast':'Name',0:'Count'})#groupby cast, find size and rename columns



              Name  Count
0  Robert De Niro      2
1      Tom Cruise      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the counts of the actors, after [splitting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the strings:

```
from collections import Counter

pd.DataFrame(Counter(df.cast.str.split(", ").sum()).items(), 
             columns = ['Name', 'Count'])
 
             Name  Count
0  Robert De Niro      2
1       Al Pacino      1
2       Tarantino      1
3       Tom Hanks      1
4      Tom Cruise      2
5         Zendaya      1
6      Seth Rogen      1
```

If you are keen about speed, and you have lots of data, you could dump the entire processing within plain python and rebuild the dataframe:

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame(Counter(chain.from_iterable(ent.split(", ") 
                                         for ent in df.cast)).items(), 
             columns = ['Name', 'Count'])
```